# Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: laravel-5.4

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing genealabs/laravel-caffeine (0.3.12)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'GeneaLabs\LaravelCaffeine\LaravelCaffeineServiceProvider' not found

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: just run `composer update` to install the required packages ,Check [this](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine/issues/44)

Comment: I occasionally get this error, so far I've found that simply executing the command again works. `composer dump autoload`

Comment: @liamvictor I believe you meant to say `composer dump-autoload`, just in case anyone comes across this.

Comment: That's worked for me.
Running the command **php artisan package:discover --ansi** by itself might tell you more about the issue.

Comment: this command is very helpful to find out the actual cause. @MsMRobin thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add this in `composer.json`. Then dusk has to be installed explicitly in your project:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/dusk"
        ]
    }
},
```

[I found this solution here](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/issues/337)

Comment: tried it, didn't solve for me

Answer (score 65):

I simply ran `composer update` and it resolved my issue - 
Laravel 6.*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - dont fiddle with files just update the composer and it does it for you... works like a charm.

Comment: This is the correct answer, it worked for me based on the same error

Comment: I receive this message already at the end of the ```composer update``` command. So, running it again doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I still getting the same error after running composer update command

Comment: It's not working in my case. Gives another problem.

Answer (score 24):

In case you're coming from a google search, make sure that you have a .env file in which **APP_ENV is set to local**. (if you cloned a project from github, the first thing is to run `cp .env.example .env`. That was actually the problem in my case)

Then run `composer install` again.

Comment: This solves the problem for me. The **.env** is replaced by .env.example for project from GitHub. So we need to create it using the **.env.example** by running the command **cp .env.example .evn**  . The command us just copying the **.env.example** and set it name by **.env**

Answer (score 6):

You have added the service provider in **config/app.php** for the package that is not installed in the system.

You must have this line in your **config/app.php.** You can either remove it or install the package `GeneaLabs\LaravelCaffeine\LaravelCaffeineServiceProvider`

See https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine.

Run the line below via CLI to install the package.

```
 composer require genealabs/laravel-caffeine
```

Answer (score 4):

**My problem was `fideloper proxy` version.**

when i upgraded laravel 5.5 to 5.8 this happened

just sharing if anybody get help

change you composer json fideloper version:

```
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
```

After that you need to run update composer that's it.

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 4):

In case the error appears when upgrading from Laravel 6 to Laravel 7, the command `composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"` solves the problem (see [https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#authentication -scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#authentication%20-scaffolding))

Answer (score 4):

Running the command `php artisan package:discover --ansi` by itself might tell you more about the issue.
In my case correcting a character out of place in the `.env` solved it.

Comment: This is weird the exact same case happen to both of us the same DAY, in my case it was a character in my passport tokens declaration

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me because I had a `ddd()` or `dd()`;die; in my routes/web.php file I forgot about.

Comment: Thanks! I had a dd on AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had left over references to classes in a recently removed composer package. In your laravel app, check `config/app.php`, particularly the `providers` and `aliases` properties, for references to the class specified in the error.

Answer (score 3):

I needed rollback for the 1.9.x version, in 2.x.x not work

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Comment: This was the cause of my issue.  A deploy script that installed composer into the current folder if composer was not already on the system installed a 2.0.x version of composer.

Answer (score 3):

Just Remove bootstrap/cache/config.php file. then it works fine

Comment: Then after composer dump-autoload

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66730584/edit) instead of adding a new comments.

Comment: In my case I was trying to remove a package but forgot to remove it from config/app.php  providers section hence, the error and this results to being unable to run php artisan and/or composer dumpautoload. Remove bootstrap/cache/config.php file then run composer dumpautoload again. After that php artisan works again just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

`composer update`

That worked for me when I had this same issue. In my case what made me discover this issue was when i tried to run the artisan command and it didn't return anything

So I tried composer dumpautoload which threw me this same error mentioned

composer update did the trick

Comment: In my case this was it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I came across this when upgrading from 5.8 to 6.x.

I had `str_slug()` in `config/cache.php` and `config/session.php`.

I have changed it to `Str::slug()` and the error has disappeared.

See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers.

Answer (score 2):

in this case, I use `space` for `APP_NAME` key in `.env` file.

and have below error :

```
The environment file is invalid!
Failed to parse dotenv file due to unexpected whitespace. Failed at [my name].
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Don't use `space` in `APP_NAME` key !!

Answer (score 2):

My solution was creating the storage/framework/cache/data/cache folder and gave it permissions

Comment: 1- add all directories in cache directory "storage\framework\cache\data\cache"
2- Remove bootstrap/cache/config.php file.
3- remove incorrect syntax of .env file

Answer (score 1):

Just run `composer update` it will solve the issues.

Comment: this fixed my issue , thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error happened to me when i removed a package with `composer remove`, then i realized somehow, something affected my config files in `config` directory, and they all become empty.

Solution for me was simply getting those files from `Laravel` repository and copy them into `config` directory. (and of course in case you need to do vendor publish for specific libraries, you should do it again.)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions work for you, the *handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1* error can also be caused by using `Composer 2` instead of `Composer 1`. That can happen when you run the install command manually in something like a Dockerfile, and it installs newest. Just modify your command to install the last 1.x.x stable version with the `--1` option:

```sh
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --1
```

Or, specify a certain [version](https://getcomposer.org/download/) with `--version=x.x.x`:

```sh
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.17
```

It might be good to also delete your `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file so that nothing stale interferes with the version downgrade, before calling `composer install` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was into outdated "../bootstrap/cache/packages.php and services.php"

I have had to. drop those files and  rerun composer install...

```
  Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue

above this error

```
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I found one more message in my terminal like: "

"Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider::class, not found in your ProviderRepository.php"

then i go **config/app.php** and find

> Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider::class

comment it out then run

> composer update

it will work fine
**In your case maybe package name is different please check your terminal **

Answer (score 0):

in my case this was the error

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In AuthServiceProvider.php line 29:

  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I solved it by upgrading PHP version to 7.4

because i was using Arrow functions in the AuthServiceProvider that came up in 7.4

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create .env file

step 2: create **storage** folders and sub folder
[image]

step3: run command `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

If `composer update` and `composer install` not work then you can try this `composer require laravel/sanctum`

Answer (score 0):

Please check first artisan file present in root folder and this error is occurred because some file is missing from your project, download new laravel project and check all files with your existing project

Answer (score 0):

if you cloned a project from github, the first thing is to run cp .env.example .env.

Then run composer install again.

That was actually the problem in my case

this is idea from @Itope84

Answer (score -1):

Check your code for errors in my case i had an error in Kernel.php.
First solve errors if any
Than run composer require ....(package you wish)

Answer (score -2):

remove the config.php file located in bootstrap/cache/
[enter link description here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/1058)

that's works with me