# Upgrade Laravel 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I want to upgrade Laravel to 5.7 because I need new features, but I can't find any easy way.

I followed these steps:-[Upgrading Laravel Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594851/upgrading-laravel-5-5-to-5-6-error/) but I found an error during composer update

I got this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986001/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur) and I also tried to solve the solution but it is not working

My composer.json file:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**How do I upgrade Laravel 5.6 to 5.7 with full instructions?**

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade

Comment: Keep in mind though that Laravel 5.7 has not yet officially been released.

Comment: Can you please show us contents of your composer.json?

Comment: Is the error the same as the other question shown? I don't see `laravel-caffeine` in your composer.json.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just update your *`laravel/framework`* dependency to `5.7.*` in your `composer.json` file.
Since you are upgrading from `5.6` to `5.7` then, you can easily just run *`composer update`*

And if you were doing custom modifications in your `5.6` application, then you can check the [**Upgrade Guide**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade) for a more detailed info.

Comment: Yeah, this _might_ work if you aren't doing anything custom. But more than likely it won't or when you go to upgrade to a later version it definitely won't and you'll be scratching your head. I recommend at least reading through the {Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade) and shamelessly recommend [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com).

Answer (score 3):

I just upgrade laravel to 5.8 with following simple steps:

1. update in composer.json with `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",` 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R75iP.jpg)
2. Then in console run `composer update`
3. Then some library cause problem like in my case `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EBt1.jpg)
4. Remove line from composer.json file `"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0",`
5. Again in console `composer update`
6. Then last Error will be in `trustedproxy.php` in line 66
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJFnO.jpg) to get rid from this error:

   a. Remove file `trustedproxy.php` from `config` folder of project
   b. Remove line `"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3"`
   c. Again in console `composer update`
7. At this point there is error so at last add all the library that we remove before
   In my case, I in console `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` and 
   `composer require fideloper/proxy`
   then at last `composer update` in console. That's it, hope this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I followed a tutorial

https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji

to install Laravel with Composer on windows. 
Being new to the PHP world, I didn't realize that 5.1 wasn't the newest version.

I couldn't find an easy way to uninstall it and reinstall or just upgrade to the newest version( at this point 5.8).
 kept getting errors :

***λ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel "5.7.*"***

Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.28)
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Project directory laravel/ is not empty.
enter mission change file name.
 &

***λ composer update***

Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\xampp\htdocs
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
 &

> ***λ composer global remove laravel/installer***
>
> Changed current directory to C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Composer 
>   [RuntimeException]   Could not read ./composer.json
>
> file_get_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

I navigated in file explorer to:

C:\xampp\htdocs

I :

1. navigate to C:\xampp\htdocs
2. highlighted the laravel folder
3. right click  rename  "laravel2"

I repasted the install script in commandLine,this time with 5.8 in place of 5.1.

> C:\xampp\htdocs
>   ***λ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel "5.8.*"***

bingo

Delete the renamed file: "laravel2".

> "windows is moving 4888 files to recycle bin"