# Issues using php artisan on a laravel 5.7.* app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I've been trying to work on a laravel app but I can't even make it start.

I've run `composer install`, `composer global update`, `composer udpate`, `composer self-update` and several other commands,

I've deleted the **vendor** folder, the **composer.lock** file, re-ran `composer install` and things I've found online to no avail. This is the error I keep getting:

```
@php artisan package:discover

  In Container.php line 779:

  Class request does not exist  

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Not sure where to go next. Any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to do is run php artisan package:discover command is it?

Comment: Generally you can solve with by running `composer global update` command and then run `composer update` command from your project directory. This solution basically updates your installer and then your project.

Comment: @HirenGohel Tried that but did not work.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Can you please provide us `composer.json`

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/46986001/5928015

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you remove your composer itself and re-install the composer. the try install you laravel packages with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing application cache using this command: `php artisan cache:clear`

The `cache:clear` command can be used to clear the applications cache files.

Comment: The thing is that `php artisan [command]` throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about your laravel

1. check composer correctly installed on your system
2. check composer have access for READ and WRITE in your system

   - after your sure about things
     check your laravel install in your system for PHP you have and find specific you php version composer connected to it (Those who have multi PHP)

then have two option:

1. `composer global require laravel/installer`
2. then `laravel new blog` or
3. 1. `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`
   2. then go to folder `cd /projectName`

Use PHP's built-in development server: `php artisan serve`